# Why does using a char** cause a segfault where a char* works?

Tags: c, pointers, double-pointer

#### Part 1

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int             fd;
    int             i;
    char            *line;

    if (!(fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT)))
    {
        printf("Error in open\n");
        return (0);
    }
    while ((i = get_next_line(fd, &line)) > 0)
    {
        printf("%i-%s\n",i, line);
        free(line);
    }
    printf("%i-%s",i, line);
    free(line);
}
```

#### Part 2

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int             fd;
    int             i;
    char            **line;

    if (!(fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT)))
    {
        printf("Error in open\n");
        return (0);
    }
    while ((i = get_next_line(fd, line)) > 0)
    {
        printf("%i-%s\n",i, *line);
        free(*line);
    }
    printf("%i-%s",i, *line);
    free(*line);
}
```

---

Is there any difference between Part 1 and Part 2, the difference between them is one use `**line` and another just `*line`.
From my understanding, both should be the same.

I am using them to test my own implementation of a function that reads and return 1 line.

The problem:

Part 1 test works fine.
Part 2 testing results in **segmentation fault**

The implementation of `get_next_line()` remain same for both.

Comment: show the definition of `get_next_line()`

Comment: In the second case `line` is an uninitialised value. You didn't show `get_next_line` but I assume it expects a valid pointer not an unintialised one. That is, `&line` in the first case is a valid address whereas `line` in the second case has an undefined value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first case using `&line` passes a valid address to `get_next_line`. But in the second case, using `line` passes an uninitialised variable to the function. You didn't show `get_next_line` but I assume it does something like `*line = blah` which of course will seg fault if the passed in `line` value is not a valid address (technically it's undefined behaviour to dereference an uninitialised pointer so it's likely to seg fault but may also exhibit any other behaviour).

Another way to look at it:

```
char            **line;
get_next_line(fd, line);
printf("%i-%s\n",i, *line);
```

That is essentially what the second case does. We know in C that function arguments are passed by value. So there is no way that `get_next_line` can change the value of the caller's `line` variable. So when the function returns the value of `line` is undefined since it was never initialised. So even if `get_next_line` does not dereference `line` the `printf` will still cause undefined behaviour as it dereferences `line` but it's value is clearly undefined at that point.

Compare that to the first case where the equivalent opertations are:

```
char            *line;
get_next_line(fd, &line);
printf("%i-%s\n",i, *line);
```

In this case, `get_next_line` is able to validly change the caller's `line` variable with something like:

```
*line = malloc(MY_MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
```

So when the function exits the caller's `line` variable now has a valid memory address and hence can be safely dereferenced.